# Gazebo - Unable to find texture

Tags: ros, gazebo, dae, collada

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I made my 3D model by Sketchup and I exported collada file (final.dae). Today I tried to import this .dae file to gazebo (by my_mesh.world file) and when gazebo starts, on shell it gives me this error a lot of times:

Error [Material.cc:93] Unable to find texture [final/texturename.jpg] in path[/home/myusername/Desktop/gazebo]

My question is: every time I make a .dae file and I want to import on gazebo (for example), always I have to paste into directory of my gazebo ALL .jpg file of texture??? Is not .dae file sufficient? How can I resolve?

Thnx

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151271/gazebo---unable-to-find-texture/) by [Il_Voza](https://answers.ros.org/users/14661/il_voza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ehm I resolved... I didn't see that Sketchup, when I exported .dae file, I didn't see that Sketchup makes also a folder with textures... Pardon xD

---

Originally posted by [Il_Voza](https://answers.ros.org/users/14661/il_voza/) with karma: 56 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0